# Why the near constant execution time when increasing workers of Spark standalone

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm told the recommended number of workers to set is one per core when using Spark. I am not getting a degradation in performance though when the number of workers is well above the cores on my computer. Why could this be?

```py
from time import time
from pyspark import SparkContext

for j in range(1, 10):
    sc = SparkContext(master="local[%d]" % (j))
    t0 = time()
    for i in range(10):
        sc.parallelize([1, 2] * 1000000).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)
    print("%2d executors, time=%4.3f" % (j, time() - t0))
    sc.stop()

# 1 executors time=6.112
# 2 executors time=5.202
# 3 executors time=4.695
# 4 executors time=5.090
# 5 executors time=5.262
# 6 executors time=5.156
# 7 executors time=5.274
# 8 executors time=5.376
# 9 executors time=5.124
```

Hardware specs:

- MacBook Pro
- Intel Core i5, 2.3Ghz
- Total number of cores 2
- L2 Cache 256 KB
- L3 Cache 4 MB
- Memory 16 GB

Comment: Your task is very simple, it shouldn't benefit from parallelization in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't measure anything useful. With such small amount of data processing time is negligible:

```
>>> %timeit  for i in range(10): sum([1, 2] * 100000)
23.6 ms ± 1.24 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

The actual latency is caused almost completely by the initialization time, and to smaller extent, by scheduling overhead.

Also

> the recommended number of workers to set is one per core when using Spark.

is not really correct. Many Spark jobs are IO bounded, and oversubscribing resources is recommended.

The biggest concern is that if tasks become to small (like here) cost of starting task is larger than the cost of processing. In practice your processor is switching threads many times per second - adding a few additional threads just won't make much of a difference.